# Write a sql query to capture below information in a single row by using pivot

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a table with three fields such as Name, Type and Amount

```
CREATE TABLE Customers
(
    [Name] Varchar, 
    [Type] Varchar, 
    [Amount] int
);

INSERT INTO Customers (Name, Type, Amount)
VALUES ('Corporate', 'General',  300),
       ('Corporate', 'General',  400),
       ('Corporate', 'Specific',  4008);
```

And i want my output same like below

```
+-----------+---------+--------+---------+--------+----------+--------+
|   Name    |  Type   | Amount |  Type   | Amount |   Type   | Amount |
+-----------+---------+--------+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| Corporate | General |    300 | General |    400 | Specific |   4008 |
+-----------+---------+--------+---------+--------+----------+--------+
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product (and your code is non standard SQL) . Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I have edited my question, can you check once

Answer (score 2):

We might be able to use a `ROW_NUMBER` trick to pivot here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Amount) rn
    FROM Customers
)

SELECT
    Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Type END) AS Type1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Amount END) AS Amount1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN Type END) AS Type2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN Amount END) AS Amount2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN Type END) AS Type3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN Amount END) AS Amount3
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    Name;
```

Comment: i want to display with same column name and only using pivot only . is it possible

Comment: You can easily change the aliases to whatever you want.  Regarding `PIVOT`, I find the version I wrote above to be easier to read, and also my version will tend to outperform a `PIVOT` solution.  So, I'll stick with what I have given you above.

Comment: my requirement is to display it using pivot concept only. can u change your ans based upon that

Comment: @user2210356 . . . In addition, `pivot` is non-standard syntax and your question doesn't even specify a database.